# How can I make a dictionary - list structure in python?

Tags: python

I think this is a basic question, but I want to know this.

For example, in the below situation:

```
str1 = {}
str1['a'] = 1
str1['b'] = 2
```

I want to access to the following value:

```
str1['a'][0]
```

I think i've solved it.
I could use it this way. when i got a key, check the key and can make a list.
Sorry for confusing..

```
import sys
key='a'
str1={}
if 'a' in str1.keys():
    str1['a'].append(0)
else:
    str1 = {key : list()}
    str1['a'].append(0)


print(str1['a'][0])
str1['a'].append(3)
print(str1['a'])
```

Comment: Since `str1['a']` is the integer `1`, `str1['a'][0]` does not have any meaning. What value do you want?

Comment: The call ````str1['a'][0]```` doesn't make sense as the data for the same doesn't exist. If your dictionary would've had the key ````str1['a'] = [1,2,3]````, the above call would've returned '1'. Your value stored in the key needs to be a data structure particularly a list or a tuple to execute that call.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete and doesn't make sense

Comment: sorry for confusing, I think i've solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sang Yoon Kim;
I think you might be confusing nested lists with Dictionaries
Dictionary is a key value pair.
Take a look at this;

L = [1,2,3] ----> L[0] = 1

G = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Now  G[1] gives a list [4,5,6]
to access the element 6 , do G[1][2]

Dictionaries are entirely different

Please take a look at these links;

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/

To answer you question, you cannot access str['a][0] because its an invalid operation.

Comment: Thank you. But i know nested list already. I need the list structure that i can save information related with the key dynamically

Comment: @SangYoonKim Can you please explain in more detail about what you are looking for? So that I maybe able to help you.

Comment: sorry for confusing, I think i've solved it. Thank you.

Comment: @SangYoonKim I'm curious, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think i've solved it. I could use it this way. when i got a key, check the key and can make a list. Sorry for confusing..

```
import sys
key='a'
str1={}
if 'a' in str1.keys():
    str1['a'].append(0)
else:
    str1 = {key : list()}
    str1['a'].append(0)


print(str1['a'][0])
str1['a'].append(3)
print(str1['a'])
```